# How to set autoclear on angular ui-mask to false?

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters, angularjs-ui-utils

I currently have an input with a ui-mask for a phone. If the value that is inputted isn't the full length of the mask, it clears the input. Is there a way to set the ui-mask so that it doesn't clear the input upon clicking or losing focus?

```
<input ui-mask="(999) 999-9999" type="text"/>
```

Comment: You can do it using javacsript and Angular. But I am thinking why you need to override ui-mask actual functionality. What wil be the purpose of using ui-mask then.

Comment: Because I also have validation for different sizes of phones, its just an easy way to input the values.

Comment: you can combine different validation in ui-mask..

Comment: As in ng-maxlength and ng-minlength but also different type of regex validations?

Comment: I am posting an example.

Answer (score 17):

You can set a ui-options attribute that sets the option:

```html
<input ui-mask="(999) 999-9999" ui-options="{clearOnBlur: false}" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really find the exact answer I wanted but this is the solution I went with.

```
<input ui-mask="?(999) 999-9999" type="text"/>
```

Just so I could use the ui-mask and it wouldn't clear the field.

Comment: Same issue, but with this solution it does not return an "invalid" on $error since the entire mask is optional.

Comment: True, but I was able to add my own $errors and check for lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs, you can achieve this *globally* in your application using `app.config()`and the options available:

```
app.config(['uiMask.ConfigProvider', function(uiMaskConfigProvider) {
  uiMaskConfigProvider.clearOnBlur(false);
}]);
```

Here's the full list of options: [ui-mask options](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask#customizing%20%22ui-mask%20Options)